# Inserting select tag in Umbraco?

Tags: html, save, html-select, umbraco

I'm currently working on a project using Umbraco and the client has asked for a drop-down menu  with the states and once selected the cities in that state will be displayed.

When I'm in the text editor, it will save tables, but once I input a `<select></select>` tag or `<option></option>` tags and save the file and go back into it my coding will be converted to normal text. It doesnt seem to want to accept  or  is there a way to insert these, and if there is, is there a way to do it without creating a new doctype? The hours have been budgeted and I'm trying to find a quick fix if possible.

Thanx in advance.

Correction: It doesn't simply convert it to just plain text but the entire `<select>/<option>` tags will be completely gone and all that will remain is what was between the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this in the rich text editor, for this to work you need to create a macro (you have a choice: XSLT / Web User Control or Razor).

In said macro you will be able to render the dropdowns you want, if you're familiar with ASP.NET a user control will probably be most convenient, binding it to a datasource.

But it sounds like you're in over your head, as you haven't yet mentioned how you plan to post and save the form. You really should provide some more details on that.

Comment: I must apologize. I'm not the developer for the project. Thank you for your answer but I really think this is his forte.

But yeah I was headed in that direction, so thanks for confirming now I dont have to waste time looking for the answer I 'want' to find lol.